# Intermittent ProviderException: API failed due to error 'The data area passed to a system call is too small. '

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, authorization

Running IIS 7.5.7600.16385 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (7601: SP1). One of our websites is set to globally log errors and we are seeing this every day or two. We're using an authorization attribute in our web.config that checks for user roles for access. This is typically being triggered by a single partial view but we also see it triggered occasionally on fetching css or js resources.

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: API failed due to error 'The data area passed to a system call is too small. '
at System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsTheUserInAnyRole(StringCollection roles, IPrincipal principal)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb)
at System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRuleCollection.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb)
at System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Do we maybe have some IIS setting for our website incorrect? Any idea what is going on?

Comment: The error often means that some parameter passed was null, when not null was expected. Maybe a blank username or password or something. You might get better help on SO.

Comment: I'll try it over there thanks. Unfortunately this exception is being generated in whatever code IIS or MVC uses to check user roles so I don't have any visibility into the parameters being used. Our logs show that the username is being correctly pulled in through IWA though.